# How to stop all pages from being redirected to home page

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, redirect, next.js, cpanel

I've a nextJS web application and all pages in the website is being redirected home page on refresh or when entered link directly. This happens only in the static build which i deploy. In the dev environment it's working as expected.
I suspect the htaccess file has something to do with this because i did something to redirect http to https and now everything is being redirected homepage(index)

Here is my htaccess file right now

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "This happens only in the static build" - By "static" do you mean entirely static HTML files, CSS (and possibly JS)? In which case, the `.htaccess` file wouldn't necessarily be required at all? (At least, not the directives you've posted here. There is no "redirect" in the rules you've posted.) "i did something to redirect http to https" - what did you do exactly? Sounds like you are perhaps just seeing a cached redirect (301s are cached persistently by the browser)?